Validation error when sending a json with the required field
I'm new to Pydantic and I'm not understanding why this is failing when the JSON has the key.
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Event(BaseModel):
    id: str


external_data = """
  {
  "id": "abcdef",
  "status": "confirmed"
  }
"""

event = Event().model_validate_json(external_data)

print(event)  

The error I get:
pydantic version: v2.7.4, pydantic-core version: v2.18.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 16, in 
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=self)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Event
id
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing`

It seems to only work if I set id: str -> id: str=None

If you want to keep "creating" your object with model_validate_json, you need to remenber it's a classmethod.
So, instead of:
event = Event().model_validate_json(external_data)

You should use it as a classmethod, without creating an instance of your model before:
event = Event.model_validate_json(external_data)
# id='abcdef'

When you call your model's __init__, you need to provide all the required fields. It is why it works when you set id: str | None = None.
In practice, what are you doing is creating an instance of your model without passing the id value, and then calling a classmethod to validate and create another instance with the given json string:
class Event(BaseModel):
    id: str | None

event = Event().model_validate_json(external_data)

# it's the same as:

event = Event() # id=None
event = event.model_validate_json(external_data) # id='abcdef'

Why is delegating the json parsing to pydantic better than loading it directly?
Simply because pydantic will parse your json with rust's jiter
If you are creating a simple project, it will take no effect at all, but for bigger apps, it can be a better option to use:
event = Event.model_validate_json(external_data)

Than:
event = Event(**json.loads(external_data))


This is failing because you're instantiating the object without the id — which is required. The instantiation will trigger a validation.
If you want to create the object from your JSON string, you should remove the instantiation.
event = Event.model_validate_json(external_data)

You can see in Pydantic's documentation that model_validate_json is a classmethod, this means that you can execute the method without creating an instance.
